# How do I add both a base domain and a subdomain to Google Search Console and submit an XML sitemap for each?

Tags: google-search-console, subdomain, xml-sitemap, site-verification

I have a WordPress website `http://test.example` and created a new subdomain with separate content and URL `http://subdomain.test.example` and I need to register both sites in Google Search Console now. The idea is that both sites are visible on Google and to be SEO optimized for different content they have. What is the best way to do this:

1. Add a new property type (Domain) of a `test.example` (without `http` and `www`) and after that just to submit both sitemaps (`http://test.example/sitemap.xml` and `http://subdomain.test.example/sitemap.xml`)
2. Add a new property type (URL Prefix) for both sites (`http://test.example` and `http://subdomain.test.example`) and a separate XML file for both sites in the correct property where they belong.
3. Or some other way?

Comment: You don't need to add your sites to Google Search Console or submit sitemaps to get your sites indexed or help your SEO.   Those actions can give you visibility into how your site is doing with SEO, but neither action will directly help your site rank better.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox) to read about the limitations of sitemaps for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is the one you mentioned in point 2.

You will have to add two separate properties in your search console

1. `http://example.com`
2. `http://subdomain.example.com`

The procedure in point 1 is not possible as of now, because the new search console will not allow you to add a sitemap for any subdomain, inside the `http://example.com` property.

Also the new search console automatically adds a domain property which consolidates all the properties in your domain including all subdomains. Inside the Domain property you can add any sitemap that corresponds to your website irrespective of whether it is a subdomain or a root domain